# How to link image to heading in different document with Sphinx and ReStructuredText?

Tags: image, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a documentation written in Sphinx/rst where I would like to have an image that links to a heading in a different file.

Somehow the following is not working and I have no clue why:

In document `A.rst` I have the following header:

```
.. _ex_1:

Example 1
---------
```

In document `B.rst`, I embedd an image and set the target to `ex_1` like this:

```
.. |eximg01| image:: _static/ex_1.png
   :target: `ex_1`_
```

Unfortunately this does not work and exits with the following error:

```
ERROR: Unknown target name: "ex_1".
```

Anyone got an idea how i can resolve this?
(Embedding the image in document `A.rst` like this works just fine).

Comment: That should work. Check for a typo of the target? Maybe you have `.. _ex-1`?

Comment: AFAICT, `:target:` only works for links within the same RST document. It does not work like `:ref:`, which allows linking to locations in any document in the Sphinx project.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! There's definitely no typo (it works just fine in the same document) so I guess this is actually a limitation (or bug) of `:target:`...

Comment: I found that using absolute links (e.g. `:target: A.html#example-1`) works but this is a bit sub-optimal since this is dependent on the header-title and not on the assigned tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same Sphinx limitation as described in the older [issue #4351](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4351). Altough in the question you're using a [substitution definition](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions) instead of the [`.. image::` directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image) in both cases the problem is that the `:target:` option doesn't accept an [Internal hyperlink target](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-targets) pointing to another document.

This seems to be one of the few cases where Sphinx doesn't perfectly implement the reStructuredText specification, because all the elements involved are part of the reST markup spec and not only does it clearly state for the equivalente `.. image::` directive that the `:target:` option should accept an internal hyperlink target, but it also gives that exact example:

> [target : *URI or reference name*](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#image)
>
> Makes the image into a hyperlink reference ("clickable"). The option argument may be a URI (relative or absolute), or a reference name with underscore suffix (e.g.  `` `a name`_ ``).

So, at present, the only solution is writing the `:target:` using a `URL#anchor` format which has the serious inconvenience of introducing an URL that needs to be maintained by hand.

Comment: thanks for your response! (and for pointing me to the associated GitHub issue... I'll see if I can get something going there!)